# How Can I Capture Property Updates on Vue Material's md-dialog?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent component which contains a child, which in turn contains a `md-dialog` component. I open the dialog from the component with this:

*ParentComponent.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ConfirmDialog
      :dialogState="isDialogShown"
      @closeDialog="value => isDialogShown = false"
    />
   <button @click="handleOpenModal()">open modal</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent', 
  data() {
    return { isDialogShown: false }
  },
  methods: {
    handleOpenModal() {
      this.isDialogShown = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Button click opens this dialog:

*ConfirmDialog.vue*

```
<template>
  <md-dialog :md-active.sync="localDialogState">
    markup
  </md-dialog>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "ConfirmDialog",
  props: ["dialogState"],
  computed: {
    localDialogState: {
      get() {
        return this.$props.dialogState;
      },
      set() {
        this.handleCloseDialog();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleCloseDialog() {
      this.$emit("closeDialog");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I don't really like this because it uses this `localDialogState`'s `setter` to perform this side effect which only eventually funnels back down to set `localDialogState` after setting the prop on the parent, however so far I've had to use the setter so I can capture events like backdrop click or <kbd>ESC</kbd> keypress that are meant to [close the modal](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/src/components/MdDialog/MdDialog.vue#L80-L82).

NB, I have had to use this "local" version of dialog state because apparently `props` and `computed` props are all just kept on this object's instance, so the names collide otherwise. There might also be a better way to do this which I am open to hear suggestions on since the above are my first lines of Vue I have ever written.

#### What is the canonical way of updating these (`.sync`'d) props in order to catch close events triggered by md-mialog?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a dialog cannot be used by only one boolean prop. That way you can't distinguish when a dialog was cancelled and when it was confirmed. In more complex cases you may have several `confirm` buttons with different actions.

I recommend to use a method like `open` to open a dialog by using **$refs** in a parent component and close a dialog inside itself with emitting confirmation events that can be catched in a parent component.